# Explanations on the proof of Theorem 2.5 in Hungerford's algebra

Tags: group-theory

Theorem 2.5 in Hungerford's Algebra says:

> Let $H$ be a nonempty subset of a group $G$. Then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $ab^{-1}$ belongs to $H$ for all $a$, $b$  that belong to $H$.

The proof of the direction $(\Leftarrow)$ starts by "There exists a that belong to $H$ and hence $e = aa^{-1}$ belongs to $H$."

Can anybody help me understand why?
$H$  is as for now just a nonempty subset; why the neutral element of $G$ would be in it?

Thanks

Comment: Because of the reason it actually gives.

Comment: They're taking the original proof hypothesis, and setting $a=b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $H$ is nonempty, there must be at least one element in $H$, say $x$.
So we apply the hypothesis that for all $a,b\in H,ab^{-1}\in H$.
Here we take $a=x\in H,b=x\in H$. Hence $ab^{-1}=xx^{-1}\in H$. But $xx^{-1}=e$. We conclude that $e\in H$.